# Switch setting 'running' state boolean doesn't hold

Tags: arduino-uno, rotary-encoder, switch

I have a rotary encoder and I want to use the switch to stop the rest of my code running, essentially switching off what I have going on.

I have this

```
boolean running = true;

void setup() {
  pinMode(swPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(swPin, HIGH);;
}

void loop() {

  if(digitalRead(swPin) == LOW) {
    running = !running;
  }

  if(running) {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I enter the if statement catching the switch press running does become false and the rest of the code is stopped. However, once released; running is becoming true again and the rest starts again.

I guess it is because the rotary encoder isn't fixed in the LOW state but I expected the running variable to be set to false and remain since it is declared outside of the loop().

Any guidance would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You are constantly toggling it over and over again all the time you are holding the button down. Every iteration of `loop()` you change the variable to the opposite if you happen to still be holding the button down.

Comment: @Manjenko, that makes sense! Thanks :) I have added a switch previous state variable to check and allow the if to only run when I want it. I'll post it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Manjenko's comment I was able to see my error.

Here is my solution:

```
boolean running = true;
int swReading;
int swPrevious = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(swPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(swPin, HIGH);;
}

void loop() {

  swReading = digitalRead(swPin);

  if(swReading == LOW && swPrevious == HIGH) {
    running = !running;
  }
  swPrevious = swReading;

  if(running) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is still unlikely to reliably do what you want, due to contact bounce.  To protect against that, add a fraction of a second of time where you ignore the input after deciding it has changed.